# Magento 2 : Display Loader While Ajax call in custom Knockout js

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.7, knockoutjs

I am using [this extension](https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_Payment_Fee) which adds extra fee to quote after select a particular payment. After selecting any payment option it is making an ajax call, I want to show loader until the ajax request is completed. below is my js file

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'mage/storage',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
        'mage/translate',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list'
    ],
    function(
        ko,
        $,
        quote,
        urlManager,
        paymentService,
        storage,
        urlBuilder,
        getTotalsAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return function (isLoading, payment) {
            var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('paymentfee/checkout/totals');
            return storage.post(
                serviceUrl,
                JSON.stringify({payment: payment})
            ).done(
                function(response) {
                    if(response) {
                        var deferred = $.Deferred();
                        isLoading(false);
                        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                    }
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    isLoading(false);
                    //var error = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

I tried injecting `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'` class and then use `fullScreenLoader.startLoader();` but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest me how to show loader image on checkout page
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show default loader in magento by using the following code

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('show');
```

If you want to hide use the following code

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('hide');
```

OR

```
jQuery('body').loader('destroy');
```

OR

```
var body = $('body').loader();
body.loader('destroy');
```

Comment: it is working, but is it the proper way to show loader?

Comment: Yes, you can use. It's magento default loader.

Answer (score 7):

**You can try for start:**

```
jQuery('body').trigger('processStart');
```

**OR**

```
$('body').trigger('processStart');
```

**And for remove:**

```
jQuery('body').trigger('processStop');
```

**OR**

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

[See example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/InstantPurchase/view/frontend/web/js/view/instant-purchase.js#L105)

Comment: hi @Sohel, can we add this upon changing country in checkout, in which file i need to use this code?

Answer (score 0):

All answers on this page are wrong. You need to add the model 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader' to your define section, and then use it to show/hide the loader.

The code below is from **vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-information-mixin.js**. Note how it calls fullScreenLoader.startLoader() and then fullScreenLoader.stopLoader() after the storage.post is complete:

```
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
], function (wrapper, storage, quote, urlBuilder, errorProcessor, fullScreenLoader) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setPaymentInformation) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setPaymentInformation, function (originalAction, messageContainer, paymentData) {
            var serviceUrl, payload;

            if (window.checkoutConfig.isNegotiableQuote) {
                serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/negotiable-carts/:cartId/set-payment-information', {
                    cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
                });
                payload = {
                    cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
                    paymentMethod: paymentData,
                    billingAddress: quote.billingAddress()
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).fail(function (response) {
                    errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
                }).always(fullScreenLoader.stopLoader);
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer, paymentData);
        });
    };
});
```